# jQuery: Apply css to image on click event

Tags: css, jquery

I want basically the same as
[jquery select image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/530701/jquery-select-image)

a row of images that you can select one of.

But I'm trying to style the one I select, and store it.

```
var selectedicon = "";

function selecticon(){

$('#iconselect').children().click(function(){
        $(".selectedicon").removeclass("selectedicon");
        selectedicon = $(this).attr("src");
        $(this).addclass("selectedicon");
    });
}
```

on this

```
  <div id="iconselect">
    <img src="/red-dot.png" class="selectedicon" />
    <img src="/green-dot.png" />
    <img src="/blue-dot.png" />
    <img src="/orange-dot.png" />
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't know. But you could tell us what exactly is not working.

Comment: Why is the click event attached within that named function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery `addClass` and `removeClass` are mistyped (`C` should be capital).

Is the function `selecticon` called at all?

Comment: It was the classnames.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As you are not saying ***what*** does not work, here is a wild guess:

Probably the function `selection()` is never called and thus the click handler is never attached to the elements. Put your code into the `document.ready` callback instead:

```
var selectedicon = "";

$(function() {
    // I would use $('#iconselect img').click(...)
    $('#iconselect').children().click(function(){
        $(".selectedicon").removeClass("selectedicon");
        selectedicon = $(this).attr("src");
        $(this).addClass("selectedicon");
    });
});
```

This ensures that your code is executed once the DOM is loaded.

You also have some typos in the method names:

- `removeclass()` must be `removeClass()`
- `addclass()` must be `addClass()`